# Not working ListView GetContainerForItemOverride method

Tags: uno-platform

GetContainerForItemOverride method working in WinUI UWP

but not working in Uno Platform.

how to do GetContainerForItemOverride???

this is Implemented Method in Uno platform reference Docs > Itemcontrol(https://platform.uno/docs/articles/implemented/windows-ui-xaml-controls-itemscontrol.html)

anyway. this is my code

```
public partial class Breadcrumb : ListView
{
    public Breadcrumb()
    {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Breadcrumb);
    }
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new BreadcrumbItem();
    }
}
public partial class BreadcrumbItem : ListViewItem
{
    public BreadcrumbItem()
    {       
        var test = this.Content;
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(BreadcrumbItem);
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }
    ........
}
```

XAML

```
<Style TargetType="controls:Breadcrumb">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Breadcrumb">
                .......Text....
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="controls:BreadcrumbItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border
                        Margin="4"
                        Padding="4"
                        Background="Red">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="separator"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                Text=" / " />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <!--  mouse over  -->
                    <!--  IsSelected  -->
                    <!--  IsFirst  -->
                    <!--  IsLast  -->
                    <!--  <ControlTemplate.VisualTree  -->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

---

ItemsSources

```
xmlns:c="using:My.Controls"
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <c:Breadcrumb ItemsSource="{x:Bind HistoryItemsSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>

NavigationHistoryControl.cs
[ContentProperty(Name = "HistoryItemsSource")]
public sealed partial class NavigationHistoryControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NavigationHistoryControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.HistoryItemsSource = new List<NavigationItem>()
        {
            new NavigationItem(){
            Content = "Content1",
            Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Home),
            ViewPathType= typeof(Views.View1)
        },
        new NavigationItem(){
            Content = "Content2",
            Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Home),
            ViewPathType= typeof(Views.View2)
        },
    };
    public IEnumerable<NavigationItem> HistoryItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<NavigationItem>)GetValue(HistoryItemsSourceProperty); }
        set => SetValue(HistoryItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HistoryItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HistoryItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<NavigationItem>), typeof(NavigationHistoryControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: The method should be working indeed. When you mention it is not working, do you mean it is not getting called?

Comment: yes. I put a breakpoint on GetContainerForItemOverride, but not getting called

Comment: When you bind an `ItemsSource` to your control, are the items displayed in any way?

Comment: updated code in my question.

Comment: have you made sure to also override `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride()`?

Comment: IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride parameter value is not null.
return value true or false same